# Не обновляется автоматически пакет на packagelist

Tags: php, composer, packagist

Я создал свой первый пакет для [packagist](http://packagist.org). Сделал репозиторий на гитхабе с `composer.json`, все по инструкции на сайте в настройках репа установил сервис packagelist и добавил api-key. Но проблема в том что нет авто-синхронизации репа и packagelist. Сам пакет у меня в профиле packagelist сейчас есть, написано что он "This package is not auto-updated." - не обновляется автоматически. Хотя все по инструкции сделал...

Comment: попробуйте в репу что-нибудь запушить, и немного подождите

Comment: в настройках сервиса отправьте тестовый пейлоад, всё должно заработать

Comment: @StereoFlo, у меня уже несколько коммитов там и все-же автоматически обновляться не хочет...

Comment: @etki делал. Не заработало.

Comment: а пробовали стянуть свой пакет через композер?

Comment: @StereoFlo да, все ок. На сайте есть кнопка ручной синхронизации с репозиторием.

Comment: 1. ссылку на ваш репозиторий, 2. какая лицензия стоит в вашем composer.json'е, недавно было сообщение о том, что packagist начинает работать как-то по-другому с лицензиями, и если она указана неверно, то packagist не будет работать с данным пакетом

Comment: @AmsTaFFix не особо разбираюсь в лицензиях. Поставил первую которую предложило: MIT.

Comment: @DarkByte, отлично, а ссылка на репозиторий где?